# How to play Zynga poker in Linux

Tags: linux, browser, adobe-flash

I switched over to Linux from Windows, but now when I try to play Zynga poker it doesn't work right. I can only play there if I run Windows in a Virtual Machine and play from there, but it's kind of slow. I read somewhere that people were able to solve this problem by installing the SeaMonkey browser in their system. I tried that but it doesn't work either. Flash is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. When I run the command the following command in terminal then it says "flashplugin-installer is already the newest version". But in Firefox I was unable to play poker.

Command which I ran in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Then I followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gerD__lYnqc).

And now I seamlessly can play in Ubuntu too.

Comment: I believe it might be better to summarize what the video tells instead of just pointing to it. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).